# How to avoid return null on my case?

Tags: java, null, switch-statement, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I need to write a Java program  (class Date) and "class NextDay that calculates and prints the date of the next day by entering the day, month, and year."

At `public Date getNextDay()` method I must use return null, otherwise it gives error. How can I avoid return null?

Here are my codes;

```
public class Date {
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;


    public Date(int day, int month, int year){
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }


    public int getMaxDaysInMonth()
    {
        int daysInMonth = 0;
        switch(month)
        {
            case 1:
            case 3:
            case 5:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 10:
            case 12:
                daysInMonth = 31;
                break;
            case 2:
                if(isLeapYear())
                {
                    daysInMonth = 29;
                }
                else
                {
                    daysInMonth = 28;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
            case 6:
            case 9:
            case 11:
                daysInMonth = 30;   
        }

        return daysInMonth;
    }



    public Date getNextDay(){
        try {
            if(day < getMaxDaysInMonth()){
                return new Date(day + 1, month, year);
            }
            else if(day == getMaxDaysInMonth() & month < 12){
                return new Date(1, month+1, year);
            }
            else if(day == getMaxDaysInMonth() & month == 12){
                return new Date(1, 1, year+1);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid Date.");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }




    public int getDay(){
        return day;
    }

    public int getMonth(){
        return month;
    }

    public int getYear(){
        return year;
    }

    public boolean isLeapYear(){
        return (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.day + "." + this.month + "." + this.year;
    }
}




public class NextDay {

           public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
              Date dateObj = new Date(28, 2, 2015);
              System.out.println("Old Date: " + dateObj.getDay() + "." + dateObj.getMonth() + "." + dateObj.getYear() + ".");
              System.out.println("The next day is " + dateObj.getNextDay().toString() + ".");
           }
}
```

Comment: You can return a new date object that has is 01-01-1970

Comment: Yes i can but, is it a good solution?

Comment: keep in mind that the developer that use you class has to follow the documentation that you provide, so if you tell him that the method return null if an invalid date was provided or it returns a date 1970, does not change this too much, it's just a practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to throw an exception. As part of the exception you could also give some explanation about was was/is wrong.

Returning a specific date is not a good idea, because this Date could also match to a Date that was created in a valid way. I.e. the Date 01-01-1970 can be created without any problem, right? So it should not be returned as kind or marker for a problem.

Concerning your Date representation keep in mind that you can initialize a Date with Integer.MAX_VALUE for month, day, and year. What is the expected output in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you return a date in the past and avoid returning null.

Answer (score 1):

Use a local variable and assign it and return at the end of the method and you can use jumping statements in your code if it can improve the performance

```
public Date getNextDay(){
            Date date = new Date();
            try {
                if(day < getMaxDaysInMonth()){
                    date= new Date(day + 1, month, year);
                }
                else if(day == getMaxDaysInMonth() & month < 12){
                    date = new Date(1, month+1, year);
                }
                else if(day == getMaxDaysInMonth() & month == 12){
                    date = new Date(1, 1, year+1);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("You have entered an invalid Date.");
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return date;
        }
```